# Highlight String that contains

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to bold all the line that contains Running test instead of just highlighting Running test.

I don't know what comes in front so I want to highlight the line that has Running test.

```js
//highlight words in the results
    $("p").html(function() {
        return $(this).html()
            .replace("Running test:", '<strong>Running test:</strong>')       
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Running test: test1</p>
<p>ssfafasf</p>
<p>Running test: test2</p>
<p>gsgsddsh</p>
```

Comment: Does it need to be dynamic? You could just replace the whole `p` element or edit it with `.css()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a conditional that verifies if the content includes and specific string...

```js
//highlight words in the results
    $("p").html(function() {
      if($(this).html().includes("Running test:")){
             return '<strong>'+$(this).html()+'</strong>';
            
      }
      else  return $(this).html();
            
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Running test: test1</p>
<p>ssfafasf</p>
<p>Running test: test2</p>
<p>gsgsddsh</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `class`, check if each `p` element contains `Running test:` or not then add class.

```js
$("p").each(function() {
  if ($(this).html().indexOf("Running test:") >= 0) {
  $(this).addClass('makeItBold');
  } else {
  $(this).removeClass('makeItBold');
  }
});
```

```css
.makeItBold {
font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Running test: test1</p>
<p>ssfafasf</p>
<p>Running test: test2</p>
<p>gsgsddsh</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//highlight words in the results
    $("p").html(function() {
         if($(this).html().indexOf('Running test') !== -1)
         {
         $(this).addClass('highlight');
         }
                
    })
```

```css
.highlight
{
font-weight : bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Running test: test1</p>
<p>ssfafasf</p>
<p>Running test: test2</p>
<p>gsgsddsh</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create one `class` and apply it to the paragraph based on the conditions like below. Use `:contains` to check the particular text are available in the paragraph or not.

```js
$("p:contains('Running test:')").addClass("bold");
```

```css
.bold {
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Running test: test1</p>
<p>ssfafasf</p>
<p>Running test: test2</p>
<p>gsgsddsh</p>
```

If you don't want to create the `class` then directly apply the bold style like below.

```
$("p:contains('Running test:')").css("fontWeight","bold");
```